# Есть ли разница между физическим и логическим адресом?

Tags: сеть, osi

В чём разница между физическим и логическим адресом, а также какое у них назначение?

Comment: Рекомендую вам детально изучить модель OSI, закроете большое количество вопросов по сетям.

Answer (score 3):

> В чём разница между физическим и логическим адресом, а также какое у них назначение?

*IP-адрес - это логический адрес сетевого уровня, или уровня 3 OSI, необходимый для доставки IP-пакета от источника к месту назначения.*

IP-пакет содержит два IP-адреса:

- IP-адрес источника - IP-адрес устройства-отправителя, изначального источника пакета.
- IP-адрес места назначения - IP-адрес устройства-получателя, конечного места назначения пакета.

*Адреса уровня 2 или физические адреса, как и MAC-адреса в сети Ethernet, имеют другое назначение. Они используются для доставки кадра, передаваемого по каналу в инкапсулированном IP-пакете, от одной сетевой платы к другой в той же сети. Если IP-адрес назначения находится в той же сети, то MAC-адресом назначения является адрес устройства назначения.*

Устройству в локальной сети Ethernet присваиваются два основных адреса:

- Физический адрес (MAC-адрес): используется для обмена данными между сетевыми платами Ethernet устройств, находящихся в одной сети.
- Логический адрес (IP-адрес): используется для отправки пакетов от источника к назначению.

IP-адреса используются для определения адресов источника и назначения. IP-адрес назначения может находиться в той же IP-сети, что и источник, либо в удаленной сети.

[Источник](https://www.netacad.com/courses/networking/ccna-rs-introduction-networks)